# Powershell - counting the number of times words from a list are in a csv column - zero value important

Tags: powershell, csv, count

I am trying to count the number of times a list of words are in a csv column where a zero value is important.

This code only returns a value if the word is in the csv column and I also want a 0 if the word is not in the column

```
 Import-Csv C:\Users\Work_PC\Documents\TAT\July\Stock.csv -Header Animal | where {$_.Animal -in $searchTerms} | Group-Object Animal -NoElement
```

Examples stock.csv

```
Animal,Someothervalue,anothervalue,
Cow,1,2,
Sheep,1,3
Pig,1,4
Cow,1,2,
Sheep,1,3
Pig,1,4
Cow,1,2,
Cow,1,2,
Sheep,1,3
Pig,1,4
Cow,1,2,
```

example $searchterms

```
Cow
Sheep
Pig
Horse
Donkey
```

Using the above code returns this value

```
 Count  Name
 -----  ----
     5  Cow
     3  Sheep
     3  Pig
```

I would like it to return

```
 Count  Name
 -----  ----
     5  Cow
     3  Sheep
     3  Pig
     0  Horse
     0  Donkey
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Group-Object will not list items it is unaware of.

Personally I would use the list of search terms to create objects and assign values, this also allows for additional data to be considered if required:

```
$SearchTerms = "Cow","Sheep","Pig","Horse","Donkey"

$GrpObjResults = Import-Csv C:\Users\Work_PC\Documents\TAT\July\Stock.csv -Header Animal | where {$_.Animal -in $searchTerms} | Group-Object Animal -NoElement

$ObjProps = @{
    Name = [String]
    Count = [int]
}

$Results = @()

Foreach($Term in $SearchTerms){
    $ListEntry = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $ObjProps
    $ListEntry.Name = $Term
    $ListEntry.Count = ($GrpObjResults | Where {$_.Name -eq $Term}).Count
    $Results += $ListEntry
}

$Results
```

This will give the desired output of:

```
Count Name  
----- ----  
    5 Cow   
    3 Sheep 
    3 Pig   
    0 Horse 
    0 Donkey
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks from your example, the CSV file already has headers, so you could simply iterate the search terms and do a `Select-Object` to get what you seek:

```
$searchTerms = 'Cow','Sheep','Pig','Horse','Donkey'
$csv = Import-Csv 'C:\Users\Work_PC\Documents\TAT\July\Stock.csv'
foreach ($term in $searchTerms) {
    '' | Select-Object @{Name = 'Count'; Expression = {($csv | Where-Object {$_.Animal -eq $term}).Count}}, 
                       @{Name = 'Name'; Expression = {$term}}
}
```

Output:

```
Count Name  
----- ----  
    5 Cow   
    3 Sheep 
    3 Pig   
    0 Horse 
    0 Donkey
```